# How to send (encode) emojis (or any foreign language text) in the Subject of Gmail API?

Tags: javascript, react-native, utf-8, gmail, gmail-api

I'm using the Gmail API in *REACT NATIVE* to send mails and using "js-base64" lib to encode the MIME message before sending out through the api.
Everything works fine but the **emoji's in the Subject part isn't decoded the right way**

[image: Subject text works fine but the emoji's are decoded the wrong way]

(Edited)
This is the gmail send mail api call

```
const sendEmail = async (message: ISendMessage) => {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    raw: getMessageMime(message),
    threadId: message.threadId,
  });
  const response = await G_POST(data, SEND_EMAIL_URL, 'application/json');
  return response.data;
};

const getMessageMime = (message) => {
  let mail = [
    'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
    'To:' + message.to + '\r\n',
    'From:' + message.from + '\r\n',
    'Cc: ' + message.cc + '\r\n',
    'Bcc: ' + message.bcc + '\r\n',
    'References:' + message.inReplyTo + '\r\n',
    'In-Reply-To:' + message.inReplyTo + '\r\n',
    'Subject: ' + message.subject + '\r\n\r\n',
    '--foo_bar_baz\r\n',
    'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n',
    message.message + '\n\r\n',
    '--foo_bar_baz--',
  ].join('');

  mail = btoa(mail);
  return mail;
};
```

Comment: ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜ these is how most of the emoji's get decoded to

Comment: Hi @PraneethG! Could you please share your code so we all can take a look? Take this opportunity to surf the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [where to start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions, how can you [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186) and share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us so we can help you better.

Comment: Please show your actual code. What you are seeing is what happens when charset mismatches occur. For instance, when the emoji is encoded in UTF-8 and then misinterpretted as Latin-1

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've updated with the code, thanks

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code @PraneethG! After studying the situation I have some questions. Gmail renders the emojis differently depending on the place; on the subject it uses the navigator native rendering and in the corpus it uses a different palette. To discard a navigator problem, please send an email with the emoji string `⛎️‍♂️♐` in the subject and in the corpus. To prevent any encoding mismatch, please copy and paste the emoji string instead of selecting them from the emoji menu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emoji is not rendered in the subject of gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64947400/emoji-is-not-rendered-in-the-subject-of-gmail)

Comment: did you resolve this issue? Can you please add an answer to this?