# Emoji is not rendered in the subject of gmail

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I am using GMAIL api to send email from the nodejs api. I am rendering the raw body using the following utility function

```
message += '[DEFAULT EMOJI ]'
  
const str = [
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\n',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0\n',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n',
    'to: ',
    to,
    '\n',
    'from: ',
    from.name,
    ' <',
    from.address,
    '>',
    '\n',
    'subject: ',
    subject + '[DEFAULT EMOJI ]',
    '\n\n',
    message
  ].join('');

  return Buffer.alloc(str.length, str).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
```

The code i have used to send the email is

```
const r = await gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth,
    userId: "me",
    requestBody: {
        raw: makeEmailBody(
            thread.send_to,
            {
                address: user.from_email,
                name: user.from_name,
            },
            campaign.subject,
            campaign.template,
            thread.id
        ),
    },
});
```

The emojis are being rendered in the body but not working in subject. See the pic below

[image][image]

Left one is from Gmail in Google Chrome on Desktop and right one is from  Gmail App in Mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your utility may benefit from several improvements (we will get to the emoji problem):

1. First, make it [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) compliant by separating lines with [CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-and-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them) (`\r\n`).
2. Be careful with `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header, set it to `7bit` is easiest, but may not be generic enough ([quoted-printable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710599/content-transfer-encoding-7bit-or-8-bit) is likely the better option).

Now to the emoji problem:

You need to make sure the subject is correctly encoded *separately* from the body to be able to pass the emoji. According to [RFC1342](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1342)<sup>0</sup>, you can use either Base64 or quoted-printable encoding on a subject to create an encoded-word, described as:

> "=" "?" charset "?" encoding "?" encoded-text "?" "="

Where encoding is either `Q` for quoted-printable and `B` for Base64 encoding.

Note that the resulting encoded subject string must not be longer than **76** chars in length, which reserves **75** chars for the string and **1** for the separator (to use multiple words, separate them with space or newline [CRLF as well]).

So, set your charset to `utf-8`, encoding to `Q`, encode the actual subject with something like below<sup>1</sup>, and you are half way done:

```
/**
 * @summary RFC 1342 header encoding
 * @see {@link https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1342}
 */
class HeaderEncoder {

  /**
   * @summary encode using Q encoding
   */
  static quotedPrintable(str: string, encoding = "utf-8") {
    let encoded = "";

    for (const char of str) {
      const cp = char.codePointAt(0);
      encoded += `=${cp.toString(16)}`;
    }

    return `=?${encoding}?Q?${encoded}?=`;
  }
}
```

Now, the fun part. I was working on a GAS project that had to leverage the Gmail API directly (after all, that is what the client library does under the hood). Even with the correct encoding, an attempt to pass something like a `"Beep! \u{1F697}"` resulted in an incorrectly parsed subject.

Turns out you need to leverage [`fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) operating on byte array or buffer from the original string. This snippet should suffice (don't forget to apply only to multibyte chars):

```
const escape = (u: string) => String.fromCodePoint(...Buffer.from(u));
```

---

<sup>0</sup> This is the initial RFC, it would be more appropriate to refer to [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047). Also, see [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231) for including locale info in the header (and some more obscure extensions).
<sup>1</sup> If the char falls into a range of [printable US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), it can be left as-is, but due to an extensive set of rules, I recommend sticking to `48-57` (numbers), `65-90` (uppercase) and `97-122` (lowercase) ranges.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found that i was sending plan utf string. You had explained it very well.

Comment: Np, surprisingly, it is not a well-covered unless you explicitly know what you are searching for. Happened to tackle a similar requirement of passing emoji as surrogate pairs in a string - glad I could help